# No 'References' title using Elsevier document class

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to compile an article using the `elsarticle` document class. The references work ok, but I can't get the article to show the *References* section title and I don't know why.

Here's a very small working example of my files. Main `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\journal{Elsevier Journal}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The title}
\author[first]{Author}
\address[first]{}

\begin{abstract}
The abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\section{Introduction} 
The intro \citep{areference}.

\section{One section} 
Some text in this section.

\section{Last section} 
Some more text in this other section.

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

the `biblio.bib` file looks like this:

```
@article{areference,
  title = {{Ref title}},
  volume = {3},
  journal = {Some journal},
  author = {Last, A. B.},
  year = {1999},
  pages = {1-2},
}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

My compilation command is this:

```
pdflatex "%f" && bibtex "%e" && pdflatex "%f" && pdflatex "%f"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could'nt you just add a `\section{References}` before the `\bibliography{biblio}` ? (or the starred version `\section*{References}` if you do not want to attach a numbr to it.)

Comment: I guess I could add a `\section*{References}` command (so it won't be numbered) but I don't think I _should_. Shouldn't the section title be added automatically?

Comment: Instead of providing a separate `bib` file, you can enclose it in your MWE, by adding `\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@article{areference,
  title = {{Ref title}},
  volume = {3},
  journal = {Some journal},
  author = {Last, A. B.},
  year = {1999},
  pages = {1-2},
}
\end{filecontents*}` between `\journal{Elsevier Journal}` and `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the expected behavior with this class.
If you look in the [template they provide](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0019/166141/elsarticle-template.zip), the `elsarticle-template.tex` file, you should see 4 lines before the end of the file:

```
Here are two sample references: \cite{Feynman1963118,Dirac1953888}.

\section*{References}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a class feature, but it is possible, to redefine `\bibliography` of course in order to automatically add a `\section*`:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\journal{Elsevier Journal}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}%

\let\ElseVierBibliography\bibliography%
\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{%
\section*{\bibname}%
\ElseVierBibliography{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The title}
\author[first]{Author}
\address[first]{}

\begin{abstract}
The abstract.
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\section{Introduction} 
The intro \citep{Lam94}%

\section{One section} 
Some text in this section.

\section{Last section} 
Some more text in this other section.


\bibliography{biblio}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The answer by Clément is more in line with the question asked so i marked it as accepted, but this one is a really *great* answer in terms of LaTeX coding. Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel: I do not understand, although it is your choice ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : even if this modification is innocent, I guess in general it is preferable not to redefine commands from an editor class, for that could mess with their formatting and annoy them. Do you agree?

Comment: @Clément: For sure, but they will be annoyed at that point already, when they see `References` heading too, most probably, so I don't care about that, apart from license issues.

Comment: What Clément said is precisely what I was just about to say. That's why I asked if I was doing something wrong rather than help redefining a command. Your point about the now apparently _extra_ 'References' heading is a good one too. I'll just have to wait and see what they say. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, if it is an expected behaviour. If we take class from here http://www.latextemplates.com/template/elseviers-elsarticle-document-class,
the title References appears.

Comment: This is another good point. So am I doing something wrong? I don't think I should redefine the command as Christian proposes since that would be too invasive. Am completely lost as to what the true expected behavior is right now.

Comment: @Gabriel I remember, than the title References appeared, when I took the class from the Elsevier's page. Alas, I do not remember the date. If your article should be addressed to Elsevier, probably acting according the instructions on their page is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this command  \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names} {\bf{References}}

Comment: This is a bit short for an answer. Please explain why this is the solution.